# fosjsrouting dumping incorrect paths

Tags: symfony4, fosjsroutingbundle

My normal Symfony 4 routes work as expected; but the urls generated by FOSJsRouting are missing the `webroot/public` prefix that automatically appears in a Twig-generated url.

### Twig call and output

`{{path(ci_chemical_show,{id:11409}) // http://localhost:8087/CIRdev/public/chemical/show/11409`

### FOSJsRouting call and output

```
Routing.generate(ci_chemical_show,{id:11409}) //http://localhost:8087/chemical/show/11409
```

### My setup

My symfony config/routes/annotations.yaml file (which works) looks like this:

```
controllers:
  resource: '../../src/Controller/'
  type: annotation
```

The controller annotation looks like this:

```
/**
 * Class ChemicalController
 * @package App\Controller\Chemical
 * @Route("/chemical")
 *
 */
class ChemicalController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/show/{id}", name="ci_chemical_show", requirements={"id"="\d+"}, options={"expose"=true})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Chemical $chemical
     * @return Response
     */
    public function show(Request $request, Chemical $chemical) {
        return $this->render(':chemical/Chemical:show.html.twig', ['chemical' => $chemical]);
    }
```

My config/routes/for_js_routing.yaml file is the default:

```
fos_js_routing:
    resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing-sf4.xml"
```

I've installed and configured FOSJsRouting as described in the [Symfony 4 docs](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html).

I ran `fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=public/js/fos_js_routes.json` which produced the following json, **which I think is wrong** since it has nothing about CIRdev/public in it:

```
{
 "base_url": "",
 "routes": {
    "ci_chemical_show": {
     "tokens": [
        [
         "variable",
         "\/",
         "\\d+",
         "id",
         true
        ],
        [
         "text",
         "\/chemical\/show"
        ]
     ],
     "defaults": [],
     "requirements": {
        "id": "\\d+"
     },
     "hosttokens": [],
     "methods": [],
     "schemes": []
    },
//etc.
```

Since this is a very vanilla Symfony 4 setup, I'm at a loss as to why FOSJsRouting is behaving this way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOS JS Routing (and console commands in general) know nothing about the application being installed on a subdirectory since they don't have access to the `RequestContext` necessary to compute it so it's assuming that the app is installed in the `DocumentRoot`.

The parameter `base_url` in your generated routes are a dead giveaway that it is possible to configure, but you have to do it manually. You can read about this caveat in the [Commands section](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/commands.html#fos-js-routing-dump) of the FOS-Js.

Set the parameter `request_context_base_url` in the bundle configuration, but doing this is not necessary when you [load your routes via the controller](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html) instead of dumping. You can see all config options by running `bin/console config:dump-reference`.

Comment: Good information. I'd prefer not to dump my routes, but I'm using webpack and Encore so I don't have a choice. Your links led me to [lHow to Generate URLS from the Console](https://symfony.com/doc/current/console/request_context.html#configuring-the-request-context-globally) which has fixed the problem.